# Not able to edit list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that adds numbers in a certain range to a list, but it is not allowing me to add them. This is my code:

```
    mine = ()

    for i in range(1, 10):
        mine.append(i)

    print(mine)
```

Comment: `type(mine)` is a tuple, not list; You should also see an exception indicates that

Comment: do you mean `mine = []` instead of `mine = ()`. If you want to add to a tuple, you need to do `mine = mine + (i)`

Comment: See my response for both list addition and tuple addition. The difference will help you understand how to add to list and tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
mine = []

for i in range(1, 10):
    mine.append(i)

print(mine)
```

all u have to do is change mine() with mine[] cuz append is for lists and mine with parentheses () is a tuple

Answer (score 0):

Create a list using [] square brackets -- `mine = []`

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is not mutable

```
mine = []

for i in range(1, 10):
    mine.append(i)

print(mine)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements to a tuple because of their immutable property.
There's no append() or extend() method for tuples, You can't remove elements from a tuple, also because of their immutability.

Use a list instead it will work.

```
 mine = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `mine` is not a `list`, but a `tuple` and `tuples` has no `append`
method. So you can fix this easy:

```py
mine = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    mine.append(i)
print(mine)
```

**Remember `list` are declare with `[]` not `()`.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to add to a tuple or a list.

Here's how you add to a list.

## Append to list

```
mine = [] # instead of () define as []

for i in range(1, 10):
    mine.append(i)

print(mine)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

On the other hand if you want to append to a tuple, you do this:

## Append to tuple

```
mine = ()

for i in range(1, 10): 
    mine = mine + (i,)

print(mine)
```

The output of this will be:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not create the variable correctly. For a list, you need to use the square brackets

```
mine = []
```

The brackets you had previously did not work out as they were creating a different type a variable called a Turple.

TLDR switch brackets when defining the variable in your program to square brackets.